# Getting duplicate results to appear together in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch index which contains some documents with duplicate `title`s. For example, the index might contain documents with `title`s like "English history" x 2, "Engineering" x 3, etc. Searching for `eng` on an ngram analysed version of the `title` field, my results might look like:

- English History (score 1.150)
- Engineering (score 1.130)
- Engineering (score 1.129)
- English History (score 1.127)
- Management of Engineers (score 0.700)

I would prefer if the documents with identical titles appear in the list together, i.e.:

- English History
- English History
- Engineering
- Engineering
- Management of Engineers

How can I find out what's going on? And how can I get the results to appear like I'm expecting? Also, as an aside, why would documents with identical `title`s have different scores for the same query term?

Comment: try with [search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch](https://www.elastic.co/blog/understanding-query-then-fetch-vs-dfs-query-then-fetch)